# PTIJ Essssssssssssssssssssssther's angels

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The gemara [Megillah 15b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.15b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that three malachim (angels) helped Esther as she came before the king:

> ויהי כראות המלך את אסתר המלכה אמר רבי יוחנן ג' מלאכי השרת נזדמנו לה
> באותה שעה אחד שהגביה את צוארה ואחד שמשך חוט של חסד עליה ואחד שמתח את
> השרביט
> "When the king saw Esther" - R' Yochanan said, three malachim [angels]
> came for her at that time [to help her appease the king]: One lifted
> up her neck [she had been fasting and must have been drooping], one drew a thread of kindness around her [same], and one stretched out the scepter to her.

The gemara then asks, "How much?", and gives various opinions:

> וכמה אמר רבי ירמיה שתי אמות היה והעמידו על שתים עשרה ואמרי לה על שש
> עשרה ואמרי לה על עשרים וארבע במתניתא תנא על ששים וכן אתה מוצא באמתה של
> בת פרעה וכן אתה מוצא בשיני רשעים דכתיב (תהלים ג, ח) שיני רשעים שברת
> ואמר ריש לקיש אל תקרי שברת אלא שריבבת רבה בר עופרן אמר משום ר"א ששמע
> מרבו ורבו מרבו מאתים
> How much? R' Yirmiah said, It was initially two
> amot, and ended up as twelve. Some say, 16. Some say, 24. A brayta
> teaches: 60, and so too you find with Pharaoh's daughter's arm
> [reaching to save little Moses], and so too you find with the teeth of
> the wicked... [see Rashi for the story of how the teeth of Og Melech
> Habashan grew into the rock on his head]. Rabbah bar Ofran said in the
> name of R' Eliezer, who heard from his teacher, and his teacher from
> *his* teacher, 200 [amot].

I think most people understand [see Sefaria above] that the last paragraph is talking about how far the scepter was stretched. However, the problem with that reading is obvious: The other examples in the gemara - the arm of Bas Pharaoh and the teeth of Og - are both talking about *a part of a person's body*, not an inanimate object like the scepter.
Is there a way to read the gemara that is consistent with the examples, and what is the evidence for that reading in the Megillah itself?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

Of course, the answer is clear: The gemara is really going on the רישא (literally!), the action of the *first* malach, who "lifted up her neck" - a part of her body. She had a very regal neck, two amot long, and the malach made her even more beautiful to the king; the gemara discusses how far her neck got lifted and stretched.
This is really an explicit verse, [Esther 5:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.5.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en),

> וַיּ֨וֹשֶׁט הַמֶּ֜לֶךְ לְאֶסְתֵּ֗ר אֶת־שַׁרְבִ֤יט הַזָּהָב֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר
> בְּיָד֔וֹ וַתִּקְרַ֣ב אֶסְתֵּ֔ר
> **וַתִּגַּ֖ע בְּרֹ֥אשׁ הַשַּׁרְבִֽיט**
> "... she touched the scepter with her head."

Comment: Per the Purim Torah policy, please don't edit/bump PTIJ posts out of season

Comment: Thank you, got it.